# Moving Table from Hive into Oracle Table

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I am currently looking to find out how I can sqoop a table from Hive (20 million rows of data) into an Oracle Table.

Unfortunately due to restrictions I am unable to connect Tableau to our Big Data platform and can only connect to our Oracle Tables in order to build some visuals. I know how to sqoop from Oracle into Hive but not the other way round and I even downloaded a csv version of the table from Hive but when I use the Import Data in SQL Developer this only brings in 500k rows of data and then stops.

If somebody could please help with suggesting any other way I can bring this data into Oracle, would appreciate it. I am not sure what the steps are to sqoop from Hive into Oracle but if this is possible would love it if somebody could share some steps with a dummy file or something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you can use **sqoop export** option for Hive to Oracle DB

The official sqoop documentation has all the info that you require. 
[Sqoop documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal)

Example --> [Transferring-bulk-data-between-oracle-database-and-hadoop-with-sqoop](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/10891.transferring-bulk-data-between-oracle-database-and-hadoop-ecosystem-with-sqoop)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in Hive I suggest you keep it there without sqooping it to oracle.
What you need to do, is to connect Tableau to Hive using this method. If you don't have enough permissions, I suggest you take it to your boss to allow you at least temporary permissions for your project.
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_hadoop.html

Comment: Can you add the relevant text from that link to your answer? This will future proof this answer if that link ever goes away. Thanks.

Comment: An update from my original question, the restrictions have now been lifted and I have been able to connect to Tableau. I was able to obtain the connection details from our server team and this has now resolved the issue. In regards to moving tables from Hive to Oracle, I was able to write an Export Script which allowed me to sqoop the relevant table, the only thing I had to ensure was that the empty table and data types were set up in Oracle and also in Hive I had to ensure I created a folder with the same filename as the sqoop export file.